# How to read one record from each Kafka topic?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have Kafka Consumer:

```
public void consumeKafka(Collection<String> topics) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1000);
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

    consumer.subscribe(topics);

    int i = 0;
    int iterationValue = 5;

        while (i++ < iterationValue) {
            ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> records = consumer.poll(1000);
            System.out.println(records.partitions());
        }
}
```

I need to read one record from each topic. How can I do that?
when I specify the value of props.put (ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1) I get nothing.

P.S. with a large pool, I have different results in the console at each iteration. Data is present.

Example result System.out.println(records.partitions());:

```
1 [] 
2 [TSDocumentExpress-0, TSDocMSTask-0] 
3 [TSDocRouteSheet-0, TSDocTMSTask-0] 
4 [TSDoctTransferStatus-0, TSDocRouteSheet-0] 
5 [TSDocTransferStatus-0]
```

Comment: does that topic have any data?

Comment: Can you confirm the issue by trying with new `group.id`.

Comment: with a large pool, I have different results in the console at each iteration. Data is present.

Comment: @Леонид Дубравский Why you would want to consumer one by one? This usually implies wrong approach. For example, consume using default polling configuration, process one by one and commit one by one. In case of any failure do not commit and events that failed will be consumed as part of the next poll

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. To transfer a collection and to execute in a cycle it is incommensurable in loss of time.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to show. The partitions aren't the number of records that you're consuming.

Comment: These are partitions in which there are records. During each iteration, they are different. The operation is the same but the result is different. I can show records in these partitions, but what will it change?

Comment: I understand there is no solution to this problem?

Comment: The same question